# Unable to bind overloaded static member functions in pybind11

Tags: python, c++, function-pointers, pointer-to-member, pybind11

I tried to bind the static overloaded functions with pybind11, but got some problems.

Here is the sample code

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

namespace py = pybind11;

class TESTDB {
  public:
    static void aaaa(int a, int b) {printf("aaaaa");};
    static void aaaa(int a) {printf("xxxxx");};
};

PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m) {


  py::class_<TESTDB>(m, "db")
     .def_static("aaaa", (void (TESTDB::*)(int, int)) &TESTDB::aaaa);

}
```

but it's failed to compile due to

```
error: no matches converting function ‘aaaa’ to type ‘void (class TESTDB::*)(int, int)’
   .def_static("aaaa", (void (TESTDB::*)(int, int)) &TESTDB::aaaa);
 note: candidates are: static void TESTDB::aaaa(int)
 static void aaaa(int a) {printf("xxxxx");};
 note:                 static void TESTDB::aaaa(int, int)
 static void aaaa(int a, int b) {printf("aaaaa");};
```

any idea?

thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is your cast `(void (TESTDB::*)(int, int))`. That cast is casting the pointer to the static member function into a pointer to *non*-static member function, which is incorrect.

Since the functions are static, you should simply cast them as pointers to ordinary non-member functions:

```
py::class_<TESTDB>(m, "db")
    .def_static("aaaa", static_cast<void (*)(int, int)>(&TESTDB::aaaa));
```

Comment: Obligatory "another instance where `static_cast` keeps you on the right track, unlike C-style casts".

Comment: Awesome. Can you elaborate more about the "*" symbol?

Comment: @alec.tu It means the very same thing as in the cast you show in your question: It means *pointer*.

Comment: @alec.tu The type `void (*)(int, int)` means "pointer to a function taking two `int` arguments, returning nothing". The type `void (TESTDB::*)(int, int)` means "pointer to a `TESTDB` member function taking two `int` arguments, returning nothing".

Answer (score 1):

Just FYI - First, *8.3.1 Pointers [dcl.ptr] / 1* of the C++ standard draft [n3337](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents/4653479#4653479) (essentially C++11) states

> In a declaration T D where D has the form
>
> ```
> * attribute-specifier-seq cv-qualifier-seq D1
> ```
>
> and the type of the identifier in the declaration T D1 is “*derived-declarator-type-list* T,” then the type of the identifier of D is “*derived-declarator-type-list* *cv-qualifier-seq* pointer to T.” ...

and *8.3.3 Pointers to members [dcl.mptr] / 1* states

> In a declaration T D where D has the form
>
> ```
> nested-name-specifier * attribute-specifier-seq cv-qualifier-seq D1
> ```
>
> and the *nested-name-specifier* denotes a class, and the type of the identifier in the declaration T D1 is “*derived-declarator-type-list* T”, then the type of the identifier of D is “*derived-declarator-type-list* *cv-qualifier-seq* pointer to member of class *nested-name-specifier* of type T”. ...

**These statements mean that we have to use the above *nested-name-specifier* `TESTDB::` in `TESTDB::*` if and only if the function `TESTDB::aaaa` is a member function**.

Next, *5.2.2 Function call [expr.call]* states

> 1. There are two kinds of function call: *ordinary function* call and *member function<sup>**63**</sup>* (9.3) call. ...

where the footnote **63** is

> **63**) A static member function (9.4) is an *ordinary function*.

**This implies that your static member function `TESTDB::aaaa` is an *ordinary function***, not a *member function*.
Thus you must not specify `TESTDB::` in the current cast.

---

In summary, you have to disambiguate the two overloads of `TESTDB::aaaa` like this:

[**Live DEMO**](https://godbolt.org/z/DEDdvI)

```
static_cast<void (*)(int, int)>(&TESTDB::aaaa)
```